# How to fix curl for playframework for Csrf

Tags: playframework

How do I set up curl to if CSRF is enable in application.conf

I tried a number of option setting -H "Csrf: ..." and tried to use the same headers in following Curl requests and it always fails.
Tried a number of options -H "Csrf-Token: ..." -H "X-CSRF-Token: .... and all of them failed with
 p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers for /api/v1/mobile/setup

If I disable csrf
play.filters.disabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter"
curl works

Answer (score 0):

Play CSRF filter check could be disabled if other header is present in request.

For example when you use X-Api-Key header as authentication key, you can configure CSRF filter like this.

```
play.filters {

  #add as many headers as you want, if any is present check will be disabled
  csrf.header.bypassHeaders {
    X-Api-Key = "*"       # any value in X-Api-Key will disable check
    X-Api-User = "Leon"   # only X-Api-User = Leon will disable check
  }

}
```